# Can two jobs in Spark run parallel?

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting confused with Spark jobs, Stages, Tasks.

I understand that two stages and tasks can run in parallel. But since all my development has been on standalone cluster I have this doubt if Spark can run two jobs in parallel. Because when I open Event timeline on Jobs page I never see two jobs running parallel/overlapping. Thanks!

Comment: As long as you cluster have free resources you can run as much jobs as you want in prallel. How jobs compete for the resources depends on cluster configuration.

Comment: Can this be done on a standalone cluster running in pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: The answer to your later question is also in @abalcerek 's comment, even though it doesn't make much sense and it's even bad practice. So unless you have a resources manager, there is no purpose in doing so.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838380/how-can-i-parallelize-multiple-datasets-in-spark/48845764#48845764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can run two jobs in parrallel in standalone mode. Basically it's require memory. If your server have 8 gb memory then you have to set max allocation up to 3 gb so whenever you are going to run second job your server can allow you to run that job because your second job need 3 gb memory and your sever have 4-5 gb free memory. in case your server haven't free memory then your second job goes in to pending mode.