# Are Spark DataFrames thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark

Considering spark data frames are immutable, are spark data frames thread safe?

If I execute this code snippet in separate threads, is it a safe operation? `eventsDF` is a shared resource.

```
val eventsDFRes = eventsDF
        .filter(s"$timeColumn >= $startTime")
        .filter(s"$timeColumn < $endTime")
```

Comment: Why would you want to execute this in different threads? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are multiple values for startTime and endTime

Comment: Remember that Spark is here to abstract you away from distributed processing. It doesn't really make sense to want to run Spark code in multiple threads. Spark will actually run it on multiple machines.

Comment: Also remember that Spark is "lazy", until a terminal operation happens, nothing is done. Your example of code will do nothing until you call something like `collect`. What's your bigger goal in creating these multiple DFs? What will you do with these?

Comment: right now I am sequentially reading data, doing some processing and saving it in loop. I want these to happen in parallel. 1 thread for (reading data, doing some processing and saving it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple Spark jobs in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568940/how-to-run-multiple-spark-jobs-in-parallel)

Comment: Regarding your statement about multiple start and end times - do you need those time windows separately (their data)? If so, there's a way to achieve that, and invoking a Spark job in multiple threads is not best practice.