# How can I run multiple sql by Spark HiveContext in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Environment:
 - `Spark 1.5.1`
 - `Hive 1.2.1`
 - `Hadoop Yarn 2.7.2`

In my code, I created a `HiveContext` to run mysql which insert data from a RDD to a hive table.

In order to achieve better performance, I run multiple sql in different threads with the same `HiveContext`. But through jstack output, I find most of threads are blocked at `HiveContext` and only a few of them are running. So I try to create seperate `HiveContext` within threads , but unfortunately I got error. After google, I learned that a single JVM can own just one HiveContext.

I'm stuck there. Hope anyone can provide some suggestion ?

Comment: There is nothing native within Spark to handle running queries in parallel.  Instead you can take a look at Java concurrency and in particular Futures which will allow you to start queries in parallel and check status later.

Comment: Can you please show us the code (reduced to the minimum). At the first glance it sounds wrong to start new threads on your own just to increase the insert parallelity.

Comment: see e.g, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845764/1138523

Comment: Raphael Roth, 3ks. Nice answer !